# A valid answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, specific-answer

I recently had issues uploading my iPhone app to iTunes Connect, I searched SO for a solution. I tried the accepted answer here on this question: [ERROR ITMS-90502 App Store Upload - Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918052/error-itms-90502-app-store-upload-xcode)

It did not work. Granted, I'm not sure why. I then tried a different solution (I admit the solution is rather manual and not as simple as the accepted answer), and what was the result? It worked! So, I posted my answer, stating I tried X, it didn't work, then I tried Y and it worked.

Now, I come back to find my answer downvoted and deleted, the reason apparently that it does not answer the question.

It *does* answer the question. Perhaps it was deleted because those who voted to do so know little about iOS or iTunes Connect.

My answer would have been useful to those who tried the accepted answer and found that it did not work for them.

Is there a good reason for my answer to have been deleted?

EDIT:
I updated the answer to be more upfront about the actual solution.

Comment: The way you have phrased it... _I tried so and so but that didnt work_ and your actual answer of what did work is somewhere in the middle. Reviewers go through a lot of answers and this one _at first glance_ might look like a related new question

Comment: @rene why did you delete part of my edit?

Comment: Because it does not add any useful information to your question.

Comment: Because I wanted to prevent that your sneering about down votes would attract more down votes. And it is noise that I feel doesn't belong in the question. But now these comments put again the focus on it, so I doubt this will end well. At least I tried, no thanks, you're welcome.

Comment: @rene I see your point, I misunderstood your intention, sorry.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My guess is that all the things that you said didn't work threw the reviewers off the one thing that *did* work. I undeleted your answer, but see if you can make the solution that works a little more prominent.

Answer (score 13):

BoltClock guess is probably right. As an addition, remember that the last sentence of your answer is generally seen as a conclusion, so it's the last thing a reader would remember.

your first version of the answer:

```
I tried adding

  <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
  <array>
      <string>arm64</string>
  </array>

to the Info.plist file but that didn't help. I then added the same xml to all the Info.plist file's in my pods project (except the plist for the unit test project) and I have now uploaded to iTC without error.

I did try the post install hook as suggested here but that didn't work.
```

The repeated "I tried", and "didn't help" statements make it look like a non-answer. We see that a lot around here. The only indication that it's an answer is the hardly noticeable "I have now uploaded to iTC without error." sentence.

Your last sentence was "I tried X but it didn't work". A lot of non-answers contain this sentence (try the NAA/VLQ queue to understand what I mean). That added with the fact that this tag is not a very widely technically known tag, add wrong flagging, a slight touch of robo-reviewing and a valid answer is deleted.

I understand you were eager to answer with a working solution, but you should refrain from exposing your personal experience with other answers, as it just adds noise. If a viewer tries the accepted answer and it doesn't work, he/she will try yours.

I took the liberty of moving your "I tried" sentence at the start of the post, between parentheses. Personally I would edit it out completely, as you're not competing explicitly with the other answer.